# Select custom columns from Laravel belongsToMany relation

Tags: select, laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

Im trying to select only specific attributes on the many-to-many relation `users`, just like in one-to-one. But using `select()` on `belongsToMany()` seem to be ignored and i'm still getting all the User attributes.

```
class Computer extends Eloquent {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany("User")->select("email");
    }

    public function admin() {
        return $this->hasOne("User")->select("email");
    }
}

Computer::with("users")->get();
```

Is there a way of filtering only specified columns from related entity with `belongsToMany()`?

Comment: It works just like that, what version do you have?

Comment: i'm currently running 4.1

Comment: So what is the output of that `users` relation?

Comment: It returns all User attributes, not just those required by `select()`.   Any field defined in `select()` is just prepending to the query retrieving related entity, like `select email, users.* ...`

Comment: Ok, you are right. I tested that on my tweaked `belongsToMany` that has nor such problem. Sent that tweak as a PR, check if you want https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4440

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you [actually can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689563/laravel-4-how-to-get-selected-specific-columns-in-a-many-to-many-relationship).

```
Computer::with("users")->get(array('column_name1','column_name2',...));
```

Be careful though if you have the same column name for both tables linked by your pivot table. In this case, you need to specify the table name in dot notation, `tableName.columnName`. For example if both users and computer has a column name `id`, you need to do :

```
Computer::with("users")->get(array('users.id','column_name2',...));
```

Comment: This doesnt work.                                                                            return $data_collect = DataCollect::whereCampaignId($campaignId)
       ->with('options')
       ->get(['title']); This is only returning title, the options relations is coming back empty. when I take out ['title'] the options come back.

Answer (score 1):

According to Taylor Otwell it is not currently possible: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2679

I have tried to use a `lists('user.email')` at the end of the query but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Computer::with(["users" => function($query){
$query->select('column1','column2','...');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer and explain what this does?