# Laravel eager loading, loaded table fields

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

how can I choose which fields I want to get from the `with` ORM eloquent. For example

```
$tourTeams = Tournament::with('teams')->where('id', $tourId)->first();
```

From the teams relation I want only to get the name (without the id and timestamps).

I didn't it in the documentation. For the `Tournament` eloquent I can do it via the `get` function while passing it an array of fields names, like this: `get(array('name', 'id'))`. But how do I do this on the `Team` eloquent?

Note: here is how Team related to Tournament, this code taken from the Tournament eloquent file:

public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Team', 'Tournament_Team');
}

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709936/select-custom-columns-from-laravel-belongstomany-relation  I just tested this on 4.2 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: There's a pull request addressing this issue since 4.1, but Taylor didn't merge that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get specific columns from the relation like this:

```
 $tourTeams = Tournament::with(['teams'=>function($q){
         $q->select('id','name');
 }])->where('id', $tourId)->first();
```