# Laravel 4 : How to get selected/specific columns in a many to many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to get all users that is related to a certain conversation. The pivot table has `user_id` and `conversation_id` columns. `user_id` and `conversation_id` references the `id` column on user and conversations table respectively.

So I did :

```
Conversations::find($conv_id)->users()
```

This is ok but it returns all the details of the related user. Based on the code above, how do I return only certain columns of the user such as `id` and `name`?

P.s. Additionally, I know I can do this by creating a modal for pivot table but it seems like an overkill. Is it a good practice to create a modal for pivot table?

**I have tried**

```
Conversations::select('id','name')->find($conv_id)->users()->get()->toArray();
```

but the result is still the same.

**I have also tried**

```
Conversations::find($conv_id)->users()->get(array('id','name'))->toArray();
```

but it gives the error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous..
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You have two tables that both have an `id` field, you need to specify which you want to select using dot notation `table.field`.  I.E. `users.id` or `conversations.id`.

Comment: @Jeemusu thanks! You might want to answer this question with that though. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are selecting data from two tables that both contain a field called `id`, hence why you receive the `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous...` error.

If you try the same query again but define which `id` you wish to select using dot notation in the form `table.field` it should work.

```
Conversations::find($conv_id)->users()->get(array('users.id','name'))->toArray();
```