# Laravel Eloquent - Get entry of a table that BelongsToMany another Table

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models: `Client` and `User`, and the relationship of each one to the other is `belongsToMany`.

I want to get **all** the users that belongs to a client, referencing the client by ID. I cannot think of how I would do that, unless I start with `Client` and use `with`, i.e.

```
$client = Client:find($client_id);
return $client->users();
```

But I don’t want to get the client. Is there a way to directly get the users?

To reason why I don’t want to get the client is because I want to select only some columns, and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709936/select-custom-columns-from-laravel-belongstomany-relation), it is still not available. Even when I try it, it still returns **all** the columns.

My models definition are:

Client model:

```
public function users() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

User model:

```
public function clients() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Client');
}
```

Comment: Show us your relations definition in the models, pls

Comment: @pc-shooter, I did. But it is the very basic one liner code

Comment: Surely you need to start with the client if you want all of its users? In which case, just do `$users = Client::find($client_id)->users;`.

Comment: @MartinBean, yes, that is exactly what I said above. But, I want to select specific columns of the users, and since belongsToMany doesn't let you do that, I don't want to refer to Client

Comment: So a many users belonhs to many clients and vice versa?

Comment: Why do you only want to select specific columns of the users? Is there a particular reason?

Comment: Do you have an intermediate table like client_users?

Comment: Yes, because the `user` also has phone, and email records, and I only want to get the name and the id returned.

Comment: @pc-shooter, yes I do! My problem is not selecting the users or anything! It is only if I want to select specific columns, then it fails using the `Client::find($id)->users` method. So that is why I wanted to start with the `User` directly so that I could use `select(...)`

Comment: Sounds like premature optimisation to me. If you _really_ only need specific columns returned, use `Client::users()->get(array('id', 'name'));`.

Comment: @MartinBean, that works great thanks! If you post this, I can vote it. Also, can you please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299420/select-column-in-eager-loading-in-eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eloquent `whereHas` or simple join.

Depending on the tables size, one or the other will be better in terms of performance.

`whereHas` method:

```
User::whereHas('clients', function($q) use($clientId) {
  $q->where('clients.id', $clientId);
})->get([ .. columns to select ..]);
```

---

`join`:

```
User::join('client_user as cu', 'cu.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
  ->where('cu.client_id', $clientId)
  ->get([ .. your columns to selects .. ]);
```

Or, in case you can't be sure of the data consistency on the pivot table, join also the related table:

```
User::join('client_user as cu', 'cu.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
  ->join('clients as c', 'cu.client_id', '=', 'c.id')
  ->where('c.id', $clientId)
  ->get([ .. your columns to selects .. ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* only need specific columns returned, you can use `get()` in the fluent query builder:

```
$users = Client::find($client_id)
    ->users()
    ->get(array('id', 'name'));
```

This will fetch the ID and name columns for all users who belong to the client with an ID specified by `$client_id`.